# What is kernel mode stack for user thread (OS Windows)?

Tags: windows

Imagine user-space thread (created via WinApi).

Beside:

- Thread Environment Block
- GDI handles, OpenGL handles
- User space stack
- Therad kernel (registers)

I heard that it holds stack of kernel mode -- 12 KB - x86, 24 KB - x64

**q1: The question what is kernel stack?**

As I understand when we perform system call we:

1. Filled registers with values or with pointers in our context
2. Initiate interrupt via INT or even CALL (Far Calls in Protected Mode)
3. Here we are in Interrupt service routine in kernel.

**q2: I think 
OS blocks user thread until OS not completed the task. Is it so?**

Maybe we are now in part which are Device I/O control manager (if we send irp packet). Maybe in some other (If we decided to create Semaphore). If this code is reentrant then system I think can get one kernel thread from pool.

**q3: I think that kernel threads share nothing with user-space thread who initiate all this work. Am I wrong?**

Comment: Your step (3) is wrong - the thread isn't blocked, it continues to run in kernel mode, using its kernel-mode stack.  If the operation requires I/O or IPC that can't be completed immediately, *then* the thread will block.  But in many cases the thread will perform the requested operation itself, and transition back to user mode when it is complete.  (It would be much slower to require a context switch to a different thread for every transition to kernel mode.)

Comment: Thanks, but for me kernel consist of 4 threads (number of kerels), and userspace can consist for example of 10 processes with 100 threads per each....Why os do need to store 1000 kernels on the kernel? I think OS can push task to the queue, block your thread....

Comment: I worked in kernel-mode, but I didn't create threads their....So I can not say precisely

Comment: It is possible to design an operating system similar to your description - seL4, according to the documentation, has only a single kernel stack, though I'm not familiar with the details.  Windows is not designed that way; most kernel tasks are performed in the context of a user thread.  The main reason behind that design choice was to maximize performance, since switching the already running thread to kernel mode is much faster than switching to a different thread.  (I'm not sure how much difference that would make on modern hardware, but the Windows kernel was designed in the early 90s.)

Comment: Ok. I found in Windows Inside 2000, Chapter 6: https://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/4354b.aspx
As exception: "Fibers are often called "lightweight" threads, and in terms of scheduling, they're invisible to the kernel because they're implemented in user mode in Kernel32.dll.'
It covers question of CreateThread but not cover the situatuion of execution thread...

Comment: As you say, fibers are implemented entirely in user mode.  Each fiber belongs to a thread, and the kernel only sees the thread.  If a fiber makes a system call, or a hardware interrupt occurs, the kernel will run on the thread without knowing or caring which fiber is currently active.  Use of fibers is rare, but they're available if you need them.

Comment: Ok, thanks...I was interested in real threads, not in fibers...) And I had three explicit question.....I don't know why I received "-2"

Comment: Fog was in that:

I like userspace programmer does not care what happens after the system call.
On the other side of me as a driver developer I was not interested in 
memory area to which I theoretically have access ...
When I had a deal with it -  I always had all the information in the input function arguments...

Therefore, the way it was foggy for me

Comment: Re the question about voting: I voted to close as too broad, because the question and follow-up comments appear to be asking for a lecture on operating system design rather than asking for advice on a specific, practical problem.  The original version was somewhat difficult to understand, which may have attracted the other close vote and/or downvotes; adding the bullet points helped, but also made it obvious that you were asking several questions at once, which is discouraged.

Comment: I've reverted your last edit, because (a) it isn't actually part of the question, so putting it in the question is discouraged; and (b) based on my experience, it is almost certain to attract additional downvotes and/or close votes.  You can roll my change back if you wish, but I recommend against it. :-)

Comment: Ok, np. I found the answer, also with your comments, and some other books

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. it is a question about operating system design theory.

Comment: I interested in concrete OS behavior, in concrete questions. It is rather low level. I don't believe that such questions are not allowed here...I think in any case this is software question, because programmers wrote code by the way for os.

Comment: And moreover - If I asked in "os theory" how things are going, without windows concretisation -- it will be still programmer question, because programmers in the universities all over the world as I know -- have such disciplines like: compilers theory, os theory, database theory...

Comment: SO is for programming questions related to a specific problem you are experiencing.  Conceptual questions about programming belong in Programmers.SE instead.  (This particular question might or might not be too broad for Programmers - I don't know what the precedents are.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated the questions a bit:

q1: The question what is kernel stack?

a: It is kernel stack assosiated with the user thread. As exception fibers is not 
a real thread and doesn't contained kernel stack.

q2: I think OS blocks user thread until OS not completed the task. Is it so?

a: If user thread perform syscall, or "trap" then we go to kernel mode, kernel code will be execute in context which called "Trap of exception context", moreover this code can see all memory of userspace process, thread of which initiate it. And really it can be said that it is the similar thread.

q3: I think **this threads share nothing with user-space thread who initiate all this work. Am I wrong?**

a: In such  "Trap of exception context" the kenrel code see full userspace memory of userspace thread process owner. When thread from userspace perform I/O request, I/O Dispatcher (in kernel mode) perform call of one of work drivers routine...(It will be executed still in context of userspace thread). It was designed so....

But  it exist other two context in kernel:

1. Interrupt context, there is no exist garantees about maped memory
2. Kerenel mode thread context. As said in msdn about PsCreateSystemThread
   "Such a system thread has no TEB or user-mode context and runs only in kernel mode."

---

*Literature:*

1. Windows 2000 Device driver book, Second edition, Art Baker, Jerry Lozano
   Chapter 3, Kernel Mode I/O processing
2. Inside Microsoft® Windows® 2000, Third Edition, David A. Solomon and Mark E. Russinovich, chapter 6.

*p.s.* I will not provide links to books because it was restricted by stackoverflow policy. And somebody give me more minuses, and I will be blocked in this forum, due to stupid questions and stupid links...